# how to write condition for " A or (B and c) " in sequelize Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

how do I write where condition for " A or (B and c) "

*current where condition is :*

```
    Post.findAll({
  where: {
    Id: {
      [Op.or]: [A, B]
    }
  }
});
```

**but I need OR condition with an "and" in it**

like

```
Post.findAll({
      where: {
        Id: {
          [Op.or]: [A, (B [Op.and] {name : C}) // this is wrong query, what is the right way ? ]
        }
      }
    });
```

query in mysql be something like

**select * from table where id ='A' or (id='B' and name='C');**

The above Sql is wrong , but the condition is what i need. Any help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `or` is a top level operator in the SQL query you need to indicate it as a top level prop in `where` option as well and use `Op.and` (or just an object with several props) inside it in the second condition:

```js
Post.findAll({
      where: {
          [Op.or]: [{
            Id: 'A'
          }, {
           Id: 'B',
           Name: 'C'
          }]
      }
    });
```

Comment: Yes. This is perfectly working. I missed the OR part in beginning

Comment: you just saved my intern ship. I need to learn more sequelize, Is sequelize docs right way to understand all concepts?

Comment: Sequelize docs is far from ideal, sometimes you need to test some variants to find a working one.

Comment: got it . Have a good one